# LinearLayout under GridView does not wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, xamarin

I am working on Xamarin app but I believe this concept also applies for android.

I would like to show my LinearLayout wrapped items in GridView as below. But is does not render as I expected.

Is there anything I am missing here?

[image: LinearLayout]

Code:

Main.axml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<GridView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gridViewHomeItems"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10px"
    android:verticalSpacing="10px"
  />
```

HomeItem.axml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:padding="25px">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/homeItemImage" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Item Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/homeItemTitle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried with my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remove the `px` from properties. Use `sp` or `dp` instead. Same thing apply to the `Grid View layout` also.

`Like this.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="25dp"
    android:minWidth="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeItemImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/homeItemTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Item Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*Grid View like this*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minHeight="25dp"
    android:minWidth="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


      <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridViewHomeItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="96dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:minHeight="25dp"
        android:minWidth="25dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />      



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this atributes. Main.axml#GridView:

```
android:columnWidth="96dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
```

HomeItem.axml (#ImageView and #TextView):

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in your layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <GridView
         android:numColumns="auto_fit"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:columnWidth="100dp"
         android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:id="@+id/gridViewHomeItems"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Change your custom layout as below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:minHeight="25dp"
              android:minWidth="25dp"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeItemImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/homeItemTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Item Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also make sure you use `dp` instead of `px` as per android standards.